# using awk to perform operation on second value, only on lines with a specific string

Tags: awk

ok. i have this which works. yay!

```
awk '/string/ { print $0 }' file1.csv | awk '$2=$2+(int(rand()*10))' > file2.csv
```

but i want the context of my file also printed into file2.csv. this program only prints the lines which contain my string, which is good, it's a start.

i would, but, i can't simply apply the operation to the $2 values on every line because the values of $2 on lines that don't contain my string, are not to be changed.

so, i want the original (file1.csv) contents intact with the only difference being an adjusted value at $2 on lines matching my string.

can someone help me? thank you.

And here are 4 lines from the **original csv**:

```
2, 0, Control, 0, 7, 1000  
2, 0, Control, 0, 10, 540  
2, 30720, String, 0, 76, 100  
2, 32620, String, 0, 76, 0
```

**Expected output** is the same aside from small variations to $2:

```
2, 0, Control, 0, 7, 1000  
2, 0, Control, 0, 10, 540  
2, 30725, String, 0, 76, 100  
2, 32621, String, 0, 76, 0
```

Comment: A good start would be to show some verifiable rows from `file1.csv` and the expected output.

Comment: hope that helps @JamesBrown

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=", "} /String/{$2+=int(rand()*10)}1' file

2, 0, Control, 0, 7, 1000
2, 0, Control, 0, 10, 540
2, 30722, String, 0, 76, 100
2, 32622, String, 0, 76, 0
```

you probably need to initialize the rand seed in the BEGIN block as well, otherwise you'll always get the same rand sequence.

Comment: thank you. just realizing this as well. right now i'm using: `awk -v rnd1=$((RANDOM%10)) '$3 ~ /String/ { $2=$2+(srand(rnd1)) } { print $0 }' test.csv`

Comment: how are you keeping the comma intact?

Comment: set OFS the same as FS; check the BEGIN block.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this, maybe:

```
$ awk -F", " -v OFS=", " '$3 ~ /String/ { $2=$2+(int(rand()*10))} { print $0 }' file1.csv
2, 0, Control, 0, 7, 1000  
2, 0, Control, 0, 10, 540  
2, 30722, String, 0, 76, 100  
2, 32622, String, 0, 76, 0
```

Comment: sorry. upon closer examination this does not work as i need it to. it removes commas from lines and adds a cash symbol to others.

Comment: My bad, fixed it.